# Weird printf & scanf behavior

Tags: c, scanf

I'm pretty new to C programming and I'm wondering why I need to input the same value twice when using the following code?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int ascii;

  printf("Enter an ASCII value: ");
  scanf(" %d\n", &ascii);
  printf("The %d ASCII code has the character value %c\n", ascii, ascii);

  return 0;
}
```

You can see that I've had to enter `89` twice in the image below.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSEFw.jpg]

Comment: Keegan, on SO, you will want to post your actual code (indented by 4-spaces for proper formatting) to allow others to help you without retyping code from a linked image. You will get much more help. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: Could you actually post the code? A screenshot is not enough... Could you try to remove the space and line return in the scanf ? Try  `scanf("%d")`

Comment: Apologies, first time posting.

Comment: The code looks perfectly fine to me.. but try to remove the whitespace

Comment: You should **read the documentation** of every function that you are using, in particular for [scanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) & [printf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf). Then compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and use the debugger (`gdb`)

Comment: Thanks Basile, below David also recommended this advice to read-up on scanf and printf, I'll be sure to do that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the whitespace (the space and `\n`) in your `scanf` pattern, i.e. `"%d"` instead of `" %d\n"`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int ascii;

  printf("Enter an ASCII value: ");
  scanf("%d", &ascii);
  printf("The %d ASCII code has the character value %c\n", ascii, ascii);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'll give that a shot!  Thanks mttrb

Comment: Hmm didn't seem to work, could it be my IDE settings?

Comment: Not sure why this didn't fix it. Your original program (and the molecule program) both exhibit the problem in your image.  Changing the `scanf` fixes the problem in both programs for me.

Comment: I don't know either, just tried again and getting same behavior.  Maybe I'll give it a shot on another IDE quickly.

Comment: Tried it on Visual Studio and it works fine.  I was previously using Raspberry Pi Geany, any thoughts with that?

Comment: SOLVED, it was the "\n" in my scanf.  Is that bad practice to do that?

Comment: Yeah, that is why my answer says to remove the `\n` and I didn't include it in the code I posted.

Comment: P.S. whitespace include spaces, newlines `\n`, tabs `\t` etc.

Comment: I see, noted!  Thanks mttrb, appreciate you're help my friend!

Comment: Also, is there a way to thumbs-up folks for helping out?

Comment: You should have the option to chose one of the answers as the correct answer.  Either mine or David's.  There should be a tick mark you can click next to your preferred answer.

Comment: @KeeganWalsh Unfortunately, no. You just have to make a decision, and they'll understand. I upvoted both of them, so they both get some appreciation for it anyway.

Comment: @KeeganWalsh The reason why your code did not behave as expected is because a whitespace character in the format string of `scanf` instructs `scanf` to scan and discard any number of whitespace characters, including none, until the first non-whitespace character.

Comment: The leading space makes no difference

Answer (score 3):

You need 2 values because the *format-string* contains `two` *format specifiers*, e.g.:

```
" The %d ASCII code is character '%c'\n\n"
```

That specifies `two` conversion will take place, (e.g. `%d` and `%c`). They each require a corresponding value in the argument list. e.g.:

```
printf ("\n The %d ASCII code is character '%c'\n\n", ascii, ascii);
                ^                           ^           1      2
```

No magic, just take a close look at `man printf`. You are simply printing two different conversion for the same value. Therefore, each conversion requires its own value.

---

If you are still having problems, feel free to ask further. Here is a short version of your code that works fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    int ascii;
    printf ("Enter and ASCII code value: ");
    if (scanf ("%d%*c", &ascii) != 1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid value entered.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("\n The %d ASCII code is character '%c'\n\n", ascii, ascii);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/enterascii
Enter and ASCII code value: 89

 The 89 ASCII code is character 'Y'
```

---

**Your 'quarts' Post**

You do not include the `'\n'` in the `scanf` format string:

```
scanf(" %d\n", &quarts);
```

should be something like

```
scanf("%d%*c", &quarts);
```

(**note:** the `%*c` just reads and discards the `'\n'` that results from pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. It is not required, but it is good practice to remove it from the input buffer (`stdin`) or you will be surprised if you attempt to take character or string input with a subsequent `scanf` call in the same code)

Comment: Thanks David C. Rankin, I'll give that a shot!

Comment: Sure, no problem. If you are just learning C, spending a hour or two to fully digest the `scanf` and `printf` *man pages* is time will-spent. It will save you tens of hours in the long run. The `scanf`/`printf` family of tools are a cornerstone of C (though you should lean toward `fgets` rather than `scanf` for input most of the time). Taking time to understand them (especially `scanf`) is necessary and is probably what causes a bulk of confusion for new C programmers. Keep up the good work.

Comment: I think that is not the issue. His problem is the `scanf()` which contains a space before the ` %d` so he can input 2 numbers. He has to remove that space and it should be fine.

Comment: Now I'm confused. You may be right, but the posted code only had one `int ascii;`, so if the "*Why do I need 2 values?*" wasn't referring to the `printf`, I give up and *punt* `:)` -- Hell, we seem to have a *moving-target* on this question...

Comment: Really appreciate the feedback gents, I was thinking I wouldn't get any response for days, but pretty awesome community to see the help.  I will take the advice to spend time man pages, definitely sounds like a good read.  Thanks David and Flikk.

Comment: Sure, "Wecome Aboard". SO is a fantasic community. Feel free to ask any question you have, but be aware the SO community does expect you to diligently try and answer it (including searching for existing solutions) before you post. (that is the purpose the reputation system serves). As long as you make honest effort with your code and questions, you will find this a great place (a aside from your normal collection of odd-balls that every site has `:)`

Comment: Noted!  That's a great point and appreciate the guidance on community etiquette, I have no intentions of being a nuisance!